# How do you make a stopwatch using tkinter in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How am I supposed to make a stopwatch start once one of the employees clicks their name (a button dedicated to each user)?
I am trying to make a timesheet for employees using tkinter and I cant seem to make the stopwatch start once the employee clicks his name. Can you please explain?

```
from tkinter import *
import time

window = Tk()

window.title("Bfree TimeSheet")
window.geometry("700x700")

window.config(bg="white")

name_lbl = Label(window, text="Please choose your name:", height=2, width=50)
name_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
name_lbl.config(font=("Helvetica", 18))

niena_btn = Button(window, text="Niena Moorad", fg="black", bg="white", height=2, width=20, 
font=("helvetica", 16))
niena_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

tristan_btn = Button(window, text="Tristan Smith", fg="black", bg="white", height=2, width=20, 
font=("helvetica", 16))
tristan_btn.grid(row=2, column=0)

gagan_btn = Button(window, text="Gagan Moorad", fg="black", bg="white", height=2, width=20, 
font=("helvetica", 16))
gagan_btn.grid(row=3, column=0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre], along with descriptions of the problems/errors it has. This code is not a [mre], because it doesn't demonstrate the problem. This code just puts some buttons and a label in a window; there's nothing in here that has to do with setting a timer. Please read [ask] for more information on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to run a stopwatch upon clicking a button (the name of the employee), you can use the `command` option of the `tk.Button` widget. It allows you to run a command on receiving a click event.

Now, If you are in need of a stopwatch code, please find a simple implementation of the same in tkinter:-

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import  ttk

class Stopwatch():
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.running = None

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        print("CLICKED")
        self.run()
        
    def run(self):
        if self.running == True:     
            start["state"] = tk.DISABLED      
            self.counter += 1
            timer["text"] = self.counter
            timer.after(1000, self.run)        
            
    def stop(self):
        start["state"] = tk.NORMAL
        self.running = False
        self.run()

    def reset(self):
        timer['text'] = 0
        self.counter = 0
        
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("270x50")
root.resizable(height=False, width=False)
stopwatch = Stopwatch()
timer = ttk.Label(root, text=stopwatch.counter)
start = ttk.Button(root, text="START", command=stopwatch.start, state= tk.NORMAL)
stop = ttk.Button(root, text="STOP", command=stopwatch.stop)
reset = ttk.Button(root, text="RESET", command=stopwatch.reset)
timer.grid(column=1, row=0, padx = 10)
start.grid(column=0, row=1, padx = 10)
stop.grid(column=1, row=1)
reset.grid(column=2,row=1, padx= 10)
root.mainloop()
```

**NOTE**: I have used the `after` method for the time delay. This is because we need to render the text of the label before we can increment the counter again in the upcoming time interval (next second). However, this can only be achieved if we permit tkinter to render the label widget with our given text. Adding `time.sleep()` will halt the render making the app not function as expected.